# PyPDF2- Attribute Error: 'Str' Object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, parsing, data-science, attributeerror, pypdf

I've been attempting to Pull data from an online PDF and convert the text into a Excel doc. However, I'm running into an error with line 10. Not sure why I'm getting this Exception.

```
import PyPDF2
import pandas as pd

# Define the PDF file URL
pdf_url = "https://mdcourts.gov/data/case/file2023-09-12.pdf"

# Create a PDF reader object
pdf_file = open("file2023-09-12.pdf", "wb")
# Exception:AttributeError 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
pdf_file.write(pdf_url.read())
pdf_file.close()
# Exception:DeprecationError PdfFileReader is deprecated and was removed in PyPDF2 3.0.0 Use PdfReader instead.
#pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open("file2023-09-12.pdf", "rb"))
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(open("file2023-09-12.pdf", "rb"))

# Extract text from the PDF
text = ""
for page_num in range(pdf_reader.numPages):
    page = pdf_reader.getPage(page_num)
    text += page.extractText()

# Split the text into lines
lines = text.split('\n')

# Create a list to store the data
data = []

# Iterate through the lines and extract relevant data
for line in lines:
    if line.strip():  # Check if the line is not empty
        data.append(line.split())

# Create a DataFrame from the extracted data
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", ...])  # Still need to Define column names

# Export the DataFrame to an Excel file
df.to_excel("extracted_data.xlsx", index=False, engine="openpyxl")

print("Data extracted and saved to extracted_data(file2023-09-12).xlsx")
```

The file location variable is a string, so calling the read() function seems to be causing the error. I thought this would work if i opened the file first before calling read(). Is the read function being called from the pdf_url incorrectly. Not sure what i've done wrong here...

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf